# Shadowing of symbols with ParallelEvaluate and packages

Tags: parallelization

I'm new to Mathematica's parallel evaluation and can't really figure out how to properly use packages on parallel kernels: I get `::shdw` messages complaining about shadowing of symbols in `` Global` `` and package contexts.

I have a test package in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "Test.m"}]` that looks like this:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];

f::usage = "Test function.";

Begin["`Private`"];

f[x_] := x*2;

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Then I start a local kernel and load the package there:

```
k = First@LaunchKernels[1];
ParallelEvaluate[Get["Test`"], k]
```

In the kernel, the package is now on the context path:

```
ParallelEvaluate[$ContextPath, k]

(* {"Test`", "CloudPublishMenu`", "SystemTools`", "ExternalEvaluateLoader`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"} *)
```

When I call the function `f` like so, it works fine:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Symbol["f"][3], k]

(* 6 *)
```

But when I call the function like this it doesn't evaluate and I get an error message:

```
ParallelEvaluate[f[3], k, DistributedContexts -> None]

Global`f::shdw :  Symbol f appears in multiple contexts {Global`,Test`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
(* f[3] *)
```

Having the `DistributedContexts` option there doesn't make a difference (I've set it to `None` to prevent potential shadowing by `` Global` `` definitions of `f` in the master kernel).

Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong? Not entirely sure about how symbol lookup works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to fix this

In short, either load the package on the master kernel as well, or use

```
ParallelEvaluate[Test`f[3], k]
```

### Why does this happen

Let's look at what's going on:

```
k = First@LaunchKernels[1];
ParallelEvaluate[Get["Test`"], k]
```

This launched parallel kernels and loads the `Test` package on the first parallel kernel. At this point, `$ContextPath` contains `` "Test`" `` on that kernel, but not on the master kernel.

```
ParallelEvaluate[f[3], k]
```

At this point it's important to realize that when Mathematica encounters a symbol that's not in any of the contexts on `$ContextPath`, a new symbol with that name is created in `$Context` (unless an explicit context is specified). So let's take a look at the example at hand:

- `ParallelEvaluate`: Exists in `` System` ``
- `k`: Exists in `` Global` ``
- `f`: Does not exist (remember, on the master kernel, `` Test` `` is not on `$ContextPath`). Therefore, it is created in `$Context`, i.e. `` Global`f ``

This means that the expression really is

```
System`ParallelEvaluate[Global`f[3], Global`k]
```

Now, the expression is sent to the parallel kernel `k`, which then complains that `` Global`f `` is shadowing `` Test`f ``.

On the other hand, with

```
ParallelEvaluate[Symbol["f"][3], k]
```

the symbol is only created once on the parallel kernel. And there `f` already exists, because `` Test` `` is in `$ContextPath`, so everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything! Too bad, I wanted to use this for evaluating code on a remote kernel with packages that aren't necessarily installed on my machine. Using fully qualified symbols looks tedious. Will try to keep packages in sync between local and remote.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If I evaluate `ParallelEvaluate[Unevaluated@ToString[f, InputForm], k]` on a fresh parallel kernel, I get `"f"`. I would have expected ``"Global`f"``. Is the ``Global` `` context stripped by `ToString`?

Comment: @wigg0t `ToString` only prepends the context to a symbol's name if that context is not in `$ContextPath` or `$Context` (because as long as it is, `f` will refer to the correct symbol). You can see this by comparing `ToString@f` with ``Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "Test`"}, ToString@f]`` (the second example temporarily clears both `$Context` and `$ContextPath`, so `ToString` has to prepend ``Global` `` in order for the result to refer to the correct symbol)

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Lukas, it seems one has to either use fully qualified names or load the package on both master and parallel kernels. I find the first option really inconvenient, and in my use case the parallel kernel is running on a remote machine and I don't want to sync the remote packages with my local computer.

What I have tried now (and it seems to work so far) is converting expressions to strings, sending them over to the parallel kernel and then evaluating them with `ToExpression`.

```
ClearAll[packExpression];
SetAttributes[packExpression, HoldFirst]
packExpression[expr_] := 
    With[
        {str = ToString[Unevaluated@expr, InputForm]},
        Hold[ToExpression@str]
    ];

ClearAll[evaluate];
SetAttributes[evaluate, HoldFirst];
evaluate[expr_, k_] := 
    With[
        {packed = packExpression@expr}, 
        ParallelEvaluate[Unevaluated@ReleaseHold@packed, k]
    ];

k = First@LaunchKernels[1];
evaluate[Get["Test`"], k];
evaluate[f[3], k]

(* 6 *)
```